# Not able to set Uniform stroke width on canvas.loadFromJSON?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

So I have specified the Rect like:

```
addRect() {
    let square = new fabric.Rect({
      width: 20,
      height: 30,
      stroke:"yellow",
      strokeWidth:10,
      left: 50,
      top: 50,
      strokeUniform:true,
      fill:"rgba(0,0,0,0.2)",
      flipX:true
    });
    this.canvas.add(square);
  }
```

On canvas I am getting something like this:
[image: The stroke width for the square is accurate]

I temporarily save the canvas Data:

```
saveData() {
    let jsonData = JSON.stringify(this.canvas);
    localStorage.setItem('data', jsonData);
    this.dataPreview.nativeElement.value = jsonData;
  }
```

And then I am loading this data back on canvas:

```
loadData() {
    let jsonData = localStorage.getItem('data');
    this.canvas.loadFromJSON(
      jsonData,
      () => {
        this.canvas.requestRenderAll();
        this.dataPreview.nativeElement.value = jsonData;
      },
      this.onDataLoadFailed
    );
  }
```

I get something like this on canvas:
[image]

How should I fix this ? I think that the problem might be because the JSON data doesn't have any value for **strokeUniform**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strokeUniform property have been commented from [toObject](https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/blob/master/src/shapes/object.class.js#L842).

A workaround is to include the property as argument of the [toJSON method](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#toJSON)

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(canvas.toJSON("strokeUniform")));
```

Comment: Wow that worked just fine, thanks a lot !